# How do I build native C source code to create a library for Unity, to be used for iOs Platform?

Tags: ios, c, unity-game-engine, build

I want to import a library from native C source code to be used Unity, for iOs. I expect to require the .a binaries and the .h header (and any other file required if I'm missing any), but I cannot find any guide around about how to build it.

I tried to build the source code directly on Xcode, but I was not able to create a library from that. XCode accepts native C only with command line project, while I need a library.

Then I tried to run this CMake command on mac terminal:
cmake . -DCMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME=iOS "-DCMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES=arm64;arm64e" -DCMAKE_OSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=9.3 -DENET_STATIC=1 -DENET_LZ4=1 -GXcode

This creates an Xcode project, I build it for generic IOS but the code does not work on unity when I deploy it on the device.

Answer (score 1):

A good place to start is the [Bonjour example from the Unity Manual](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PluginsForIOS.html). This at least gives you a working iOS plugin as a starting point.

You include the files in your Unity project, and build for iOS. You will notice that the files under Plugins/iOS are automatically included in the generated Xcode project. They will only be compiled when you build/run your Xcode project.

Careful, an iOS plugin is not the same as a MacOS plugin. For a MacOS plugin, you will need to create the bundle and include this into your UnityProject. The DllImport decorator will also be different on your C# code. For iOS it is `"__Internal"`, but for MacOS it is the name of the bundle.

If you are trying to interface with a third party library, you may need to manually modify the library search paths of your Xcode project to correctly locate your .a and .h files when building and linking.

As a side note, when including a third party .a binary, verify that it conforms to the iOS architecture requirements, otherwise your app may be rejected when submitting to the app-store.

Comment: Thank for the info!
The decoration and the plugin setup should be already in place, I just need to build it to try it on the device.

To link the binaries I should just set them under Plugin/iOs folder [source](https://twnkls.com/en/blogs/howto-native-ios-plugins-for-unity3d-2/). But I need the binaries to check it.

"_verify that it conforms to the iOS architecture requirements_"

Yes, this is part of the question. I would need to understand where and how to set the architecture when I build the code to implement the binaries.

Comment: I don't think just putting the binaries in the Plugins/iOS folder is enough to have them linked to the final Xcode build. You will most likely need to add the binary as a dependency in Xcode  (under General -> Linked Frameworks and Libraries). Also, how do you plan to communicate with the binary from Unity ? Normally you need to have an `extern "C"`block with functions that act as a bridge between your C# and the library (see `BonjourClientImpl.mm` for an example)

Comment: Also, if your external library is relatively self contained, and you have the source code, all you may need to do is include its source files in Plugin/iOS, provide a .mm file with the right `extern "C"` section, and let Xcode handle the build for you. I have successfully done this in the past with a third party library. The advantage is you don't have to mess around with including dependencies.

Comment: One of my collegues built the project from CMake, that created an XCode project. Then from XCode I built the binary .a file. After that I included both .a file and the .h header of the source C native code under Plugin/iOs and everything seems to be working. I don't think .mm is required because I'm not using a Objective-C but a native C source. Maybe it could be working by placing the .c code directly instead of the binaries.

I'm not submitting the answer because I would not be able to reproduce the build and I'm still not entirely sure if this is totally stable.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. When you say everything is working, you mean you able to call functions in your library when deployed on the iOS device?

Comment: Yes. At least for the moment we can call methods of the C library from ios Device.
Consider that everything was setup using Unity guide (IE adding all the "__Internal" decorators). And the game has been buillt with [this](http://www.allcivilizedplanets.com/blog/2015/6/12/automated-builds-from-unity3d-to-ios).
I still won't be able to answer this question because I can't be sure of the specific steps for how to build the library from the source (and I'm not sure if I can just simply remove the built library entirely and implement just the source code).